# My .indexOn rule added to Security & Rules isn't taken into account

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to set up custom indexes on my firebase data for sorting on certain fields.

Here is my data:

GET https://testindexon.firebaseio.com/.json

`{
    "key1": {
        "age": 80,
        "name": "zabc"
    },
    "key2": {
        "age": 90,
        "name": "defg"
    },
    "key3": {
        "age": 10,
        "name": "hijk"
    }
}`

Here are my security rules:

`{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "testindexon": {
          ".indexOn": "age"
      }
    }
}`

When I try to orderBy the indexed "age" property, I get an error:

GET https://testindexon.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="age"

Error 400 (Bad request)

`{
    "error": "Index not defined"
}`

I can get around the 400 Error by rewriting my security rules as follows:

`{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
          ".indexOn": ["age", "name"]
    }
}`

But then when I try to order by one of the properties, nothing special happens (results aren't sorted):

GET ....firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="age"

`{
    "key1": {
        "age": 80,
        "name": "zabc"
    },
    "key2": {
        "age": 90,
        "name": "defg"
    },
    "key3": {
        "age": 10,
        "name": "hijk"
    }
}`

Am I missing something ? I would appreciate any help.

Best,

State variable

Comment: The REST API returns the results unsorted. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-ordered-data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen indeed thanks for the pointer. However the user doc also shows the following example at one point:

"Ordering by a specified child key

We can order nodes by a common child key by passing that key to the orderBy parameter. For example, to read all dinosaurs ordered by height, we can do the following:

curl ...dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="height"&print=pretty
"

(cf https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-queries)

Confusing !

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The doc also says: "Indexes are not required for development unless you are using the REST API. The realtime client libraries can execute ad-hoc queries without specifying indexes. Performance will degrade as the data you query grows, so it is important to add indexes before you launch your app if you anticipate querying a large set of data."

(cf https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html)

So I think we may be missing something here. It sounds like indexes can be defined for the REST API...

Comment: What I pointed at initially is really how it is: the REST API will not return the child nodes in any specific order, simply because in a JSON object you cannot define an order of the child nodes. You *can* however filter the child nodes, which is why `orderBy...` is still relevant on the REST API. I'll file a task to improve the docs as they are indeed a bit too generic here.

Comment: So the REST API can *order* the data, which is what it needs to do for filtering it. But a regular REST GET request cannot *return* ordered data. But as I said: the documentation on that could be better.

Comment: It looks to me like your .indexOn is on the wrong path. You're fetching root, but put the indexon under the child path `testindexon/`. Thus, your URL would need to be https://testindexon.firebaseio.com/testindexon/.json in order to take advantage of the orderBy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Firebase documentation on retrieving data through its REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-ordered-data):

> THE REST API RETURNS UNSORTED RESULTS
>
> JSON interpreters do not enforce any ordering on the result set. While orderBy can be used in combination with startAt, endAt, limitToFirst, or limitToLast to return a subset of the data, the returned results will not be sorted. Therefore, it may be necessary to manually sort the results if ordering is important.

There are indeed samples and others fragments in that documentation that seem to suggest otherwise. But the above statement is true.

Keep in mind that the `orderBy` parameter is used for more things than just *returning* ordered results. You'd also use the method to filter the results, i.e.

```
GET 'https://testindexon.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="age"&equalTo=90'
```

Or you would order to return a limited number of results:

```
GET 'https://testindexon.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="age"&limitToFirst=10'
```

So in these cases, the child nodes are sorted on the server and then filtered, but the return value will/may still contain the remaining child nodes in an undetermined order.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your .indexOn is on the wrong path. You're fetching root, but put the .indexOn under the child path `testindexon/`. Thus, your URL would need to be `https://testindexon.firebaseio.com/testindexon/.json` in order to take advantage of the orderBy.

Comment: OPs second `rules` snippet has the `.indexOn` in the correct location.