# Curling Firebase with orderByChild and equalTo?

Tags: curl, firebase

I'm attempting to use the REST API to query Firebase (just using curl for now).

I've attempted to query using `orderByChild` which returns results, but they do not appear to be sorting.

```
curl -k 'https://shining-fire-6711.firebaseio.com/todos.json?orderByChild="name"'
```

I have also tried to use `orderByChild` in conjunction with the `equalTo` clause, but that just returns an error `orderBy must be defined when other query parameters are defined`

```
curl -k 'https://shining-fire-6711.firebaseio.com/todos.json?orderByChild="name"&equalTo="c"'
```

Comment: Firebase's REST API returns a single JSON object. Since the order of keys within a JSON object is undetermined, the results are also unordered. The orderBy operation in the REST API is therefor only useful to limit the results that are returned, you'll have to (re)sort them client-side. The documentation is "not very clear" on this point, which we intend to fix in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My .indexOn rule added to Security & Rules isn't taken into account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583177/my-indexon-rule-added-to-security-rules-isnt-taken-into-account)

Comment: Your last query should use `orderBy` and not `orderByChild` (which is not an existing parameter for the REST API). So `curl -k 'https://shining-fire-6711.firebaseio.com/todos.json?orderBy="name"&equalTo="c"'` would work, but you'll need to add an index to the rules.json.

Comment: I'm sorry, where do you find docs for `orderByChild` in REST API? There is only `orderBy` query

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Not really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583177/my-indexon-rule-added-to-security-rules-isnt-taken-into-account.  I have the proper index setup.  I didn't realize that the orderBy doesn't actually creating an ordering; which is quite counterintuitive, but my larger issue was using `orderByChild` in the request.  I didn't realize that option does not exist within the REST API.  Thanks @Kirill Slatin

Comment: @KirillSlatin I saw `orderByChild` in the web documentation and made the mistake of using it in my request; didn't realize it was not available to the REST API.  While it doesn't work and `orderBy` should be used, if you use `orderByChild="field"` it returns a valid json dataset so this furthered my confusion.

Comment: sure, it ignores all unknown query params

Comment: What is the workaround to use orderBychild in RestApi, Can we use OrderBy with a nested path

Answer (score 6):

According to [Firebase Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-value):

> Indexes are not required for development **unless you are using the REST
>   API**. The realtime client libraries can execute ad-hoc queries without
>   specifying indexes. Performance will degrade as the data you query
>   grows, so it is important to add indexes before you launch your app if
>   you anticipate querying a large set of data.

This document is hiding somewhere deep which spent me hours until I find that.

In addition execute some example (which obtained from the [another Firebase Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering)). I tried running the following code on console

`curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="height"&print=pretty'`

It returns some data. Here is part of the returned value

```
{
  "linhenykus" : {
    "appeared" : -85000000,
    "height" : 0.6,
    "length" : 1,
    "order" : "theropoda",
    "vanished" : -75000000,
    "weight" : 3
  }
}
```

It shows that you don't need to use the parameter `orderByChild`, using `orderBy` does the trick.